# Hide Tab Bar on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitabbar

I have this UITabBar, created with this code in AppDelegate.m:

```
UITabBarController *tbc = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

BarsViewController *bvc = [[BarsViewController alloc] init];
StopwatchViewController *svc = [[StopwatchViewController alloc] init];
TimerViewController *tvc = [[TimerViewController alloc] init];

[bvc.tabBarItem setTitle:@"Clock"];
[svc.tabBarItem setTitle:@"Stopwatch"];
[tvc.tabBarItem setTitle:@"Timer"];

[tbc setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:svc, bvc, tvc, nil] animated:YES];

[tbc setSelectedIndex:1];
```

I want to have the tab bar hidden completely and not to push up any of the layers on the screen. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: so just only use your tabbarcontroller name .tabbar.hidden=true;.

Comment: then why diid you created it?

Answer (score 2):

In your first viewcontroller add this

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
     self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you wanna show and hide your tabbar multiple times from different view controllers then implement below code in your appDelegate.m file

```
- (void) hideTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller
{
int height = 480;
if (([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    || ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft))
{
    height = 320;
}
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
{
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
    {
        [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, height, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
    }
    else {
        [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, height)];
    }
}
[UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void) showTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller
{
int height = 431;
if (([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    || ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft))
{
    height = 271;
}
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
{
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
    {
        [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, height, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
    }
    else {
        [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, height)];
    }
}
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: This didn't work; The tab bar didn't disappear and everything was pushed up leaving a black bar at the bottom.

Comment: call this at your desired viewController [appDelegate hideTabBar:appDelegate. tbc];

and it works perfect i've just checked and it worked fine if you run this code in iphone 5 then set the frame accordingly like instead of 480 use 568 ok.